# Updating values in a list

Tags: list

I have the following variable composed of two numbers.

```
(defvar recorder '(0 0))
```

Inside some function I want to update the first value in `recorder`.  And in another function, I want to update the second value.  What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setf](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Generalized-Variables.html) for that.

```lisp
(let ((recorder '(0 0)))
  (setf (car recorder) 1)
  (setf (cadr recorder) 2)
  recorder)
```

Alternatively you could use [setcar and setcdr](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/car-cdr-_0026-cons.html).

I have created the links so that you can click them to read how they work.